# Accidentally changed "documents" location to user directory, can't change back

Tags: windows-10

I accidentally changed the Documents library to my user directory, and now it won't let me change back.

If i try changing the folder to another location, e.g. E:\Documents (without moving any files) I get this message:

[image: Error Header: The can't be moved here; Error Message: Can't move folder because there is a folder in the same location that can't be redirected]

Is there some value I can change somewhere that will tell Windows that the Documents Library is somewhere else without going through the normal move process?

Comment: Have you tried [System Restore](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) back to before you changed it?

Comment: Too much time went before I discovered that i had made the error. I don't dare making a recovery that far back in time. (It was way before the creators upgrade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in regedit:

Open `regedit` and go to the path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Change the value of the binary `Personal` to:

From

```
%USERPROFILE%
```

To

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents
```

Comment: Apparently i found the answer to my own question.